# How to integrate $y' = x(1+y)(2-y)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

$$y' = x(1+y)(2-y)$$
I have been stuck on this problem for a little while and do not know what I should set as ***v*** (some random variable for substitution) if I were to approach this problem as a separable equation.

I had tried setting ***v*** equal to all three terms, $x, 1+y,$ and $2-y$, with no luck and then ***v*** equal to $((1+y)(2-y))$ but did not succeed with that either.

---

**Edit1:**

Here is my solution :
$$ \frac 1 3(\ln|y+1|-\ln|y-2|)= \frac {x^2}2+C_1 $$
$$ \ln \left | \frac {y+1}{y-2} \right |= \frac {3}2x^2+C $$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  What's $v$?  $\;\int\dfrac1{(1+y)(2-y)}dy=\int x dx$

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Have you tried approaching it as a separable function and, if so, what did you get (please update your question text with the details)?

Comment: Separate then use fraction decomposition method for the integral $dy$

Comment: for a [separable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables) equation like this one, you don't need substitution

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I wrote my answer, rather sloppily as I am unfamiliar with MathJax, on the post of LostInSpace.

Comment: Shailesh I edited your answer and I added your solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac {dy}{dx} = x(1+y)(2-y)$$
Separate and integrate :
$$\int \frac {dy}{(y+1)(y-2)}=-\int xdx$$
Then use fraction decomposition method for the left integral:
$$-\frac 13\int \frac {dy}{y+1}+\frac 1 3\int \frac {dy}{y-2}=-\int xdx$$
Can you take it from here ?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I can't believe how easy that actually was. I am unfamiliar with MathJax formatting so writing my answer plainly will be messy, but here goes: ((ln(y+1)-ln(y-2))/3)=((x^2)/2)+C          I apologize for the mess!

Comment: @ShaileshB. No problem I edit your question and added your solution formatted.